# Limit of (cot x)/x when x->infinity

Tags: limits

The rule say that:

```
Limit x->Anything 0*(sin x)=0.
Limit x->Anything 0*(cos x)=0.
```

Does this apply here too?

```
Limit x->infinity (1/x)*(|cot x|)=0.
```

I mean, Does the rule still apply here: Limit x->Anything 0*[0,infinity)=0  ?

Comment: No, it doesn't apply here, since $|\cot x|$ is not bounded. The correct rule is $$\lim_{x \to anything}(0)(\mbox{bounded})=0$$

Comment: Okay thats what I was looking for, thank you.  Please right it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't apply here, since $|\cot x|$ is not bounded. The correct rule is $$\lim_{x \to anything}(0)(\mbox{bounded})=0$$

Moreover, the limit
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{|\cot x|}{x}$$ does not exist.